# Pass SQL function value to ASP form

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I created A function as below in SQL server ,i want to get the max ID then pass it to the ASP form in IDtextbox
how shall i do that ? "if there any problem with the Function please fix it and advice about C# code"
if i had another procedure do different thing , can i execute it with the function at the same time with same connection ?

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Justification_MaxGroupID] ()
    RETURNS INT
AS

BEGIN

    Declare @MaxGroupID int

    SELECT  @MaxGroupID = Max([Justification_Group_ID]) +1 from [dbo].[TBL_Justification]

    RETURN  @MaxGroupID;

end

go

Declare @ID int

Select @ID= [dbo].[FN_Justification_MaxGroupID] ()

Select @ID
```

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: as titled i want C# code to get Scalar value from SQL Server function

Comment: Did the reply I gave answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteScalar() of SqlCommand

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdt3k85x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx